How can I manage water where two roofs flank an opening?
My father's house has an opening in the back porch roof.
Water runs down that ridge and creates a waterfall. He asked me to close it, but both sides are level. If I put 2x4 and plywood at an angle, that creates a gap between the house shingle and plywood. Do I need to add flashing so the new shingles don’t sag? I also barely have space for my fascia at the end. But if I leave it level I’m afraid water will collect and slowly create a leak.


More images

Nice pictures, they explain the situation quite well. However the design looks like you will just collect water on level plywood. You need a waterproof material, a slope and a place where the rain water is supposed to go.

This isn't something you want to cobble together. To properly drain the roof with no opening the existing roofs would need to be extended on their current slopes until they intersect. Level valleys are not viable. You'll have pooling water and ice dams, if you're in a freezing climate.
You have two options:

Install gutters all the way around the perimeter of the opening, dropping to the ground at the most sensible location.

Hire a contractor to evaluate your roof situation and design a new roof.


With option 1, you could also install a raised panel to shelter the gap. It would drain onto the existing roof planes and then into the gutter. It would be above the existing roof so that there's no potential for backing up of drain water. Think along the lines of an umbrella.

Your issue is that you are draining from three roof slopes into a small area. If you put an eavestrough in to catch the runoff you will have very little opening left. To allow for light and drainage, install a covering over the opening like a raised skylight (with a base on it) that is sized slightly larger than the opening and testing on the roof joists. Flash the short end so that it diverts water to the sides and flash the long ends so that it creates gutters to the outside. Install an eavestrough to divert the runoff away from the house.
